# Databinding in ItemContainterStyle - WPF - MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, mvvm-light, itemcontainerstyle

I'm creating a custom ListBox with an ItemContainer that uses a Grid. The goal is to have each Item be added to a specific column, row, and have a specific rowspan. These numbers are set as bindable properties in an ObservableCollection ScheduledCourses. On the DataTemplate I'm able to specify the DataType and then able to bind from within the collection. But I can't specify a DataType on Style. How do I set the values in BlockPlacement to bind the desired properties?

PS. I'm using MVVM Light.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CoursesByDay" Source="{Binding ScheduledCourses}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MeetsOn" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ScheduleBlock" DataType="vm:ScheduleBlockViewModel">
        <userControls:ScheduleBlock />
    </DataTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ScheduleDayGrid">
        <!--  Replace with Schedule Day Grid  -->
        <Grid Name="ScheduleDayGrid"
              Width="400"
              Initialized="ScheduleDayGridInitialized"
              ShowGridLines="True" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="BlockPlacement" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=ScheduledCourses[].TimeSlotIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding ScheduledCourses[].StartTimeIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding ScheduledCourses[].DurationIndex}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Mode="OneWay"
             Path="ScheduleGrid"
             Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: When you run your app, does the output window show any binding errors?

Comment: I got it! I just needed some sleep. I ended up adding in a setter with a DataContext Property.